# How can I configure Android so that the keyboard appears by default when clicking on the settings search box?

Tags: settings, keyboard, search, android-12, google-pixel-6

When I click on  the search box in the settings,  by default no keyboard appears:

[image]

I  have to click again on the search box for the keyboard to appear.

Instead  I would like the keyboard to appear by default:

[image]

How can I configure Android so that the keyboard appears by default when clicking on the settings search box?

I use Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759253/show-keyboard-automatically) on stack overflow, this is defined by the application. The app must request the keyboard to be displayed when the cursor is on the field.
They say that, in small screen devices, the keyboard occupy lots of space, covering important views. So it's better to not display the keyboard by default, and let the developer implement if he wants to display it.